# MongoDB extension not loading

Tags: php, mongodb

When I install php mongodb extension on my windows, a warning is generated, however it works in CLI though. Would andyone give me any advice? Thanks!

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'd:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_mongodb.dll' -
\xef\xbf\xbd\xd2\xb2\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd
\xd6\xb8\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd
\xc4\xa3\xef\xbf\xbd\xe9\xa1\xa3\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

[image]
[image]